# WF4 error when calling operations (receive activities) on long running workflow service

Tags: .net, wcf, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

The error:
The execution of an InstancePersistenceCommand was interrupted because the instance '42ca66e7-35e3-462e-9594-a98ee009d2e2' has not yet been persisted to the instance store.

This happens when I call the 2nd receive activity on an existing workflow instance that has been unloaded from memory. If the instance is still in memory, I don't have the problem. The instance gets unloaded after waiting for 1 minute or stopping the debugger.

I can see a record in the System.Activities.DurableInstancing.InstancesTable table with the id 42CA66E7-35E3-462E-9594-A98EE009D2E2.

Any idea why I'm having this problem?

## Update

It seems like my state of the workflow isn't being persisted and/or persistence isn't happening properly. [Here's is a workflow instance record in the System.Activities.DurableInstancing.InstancesTable table.](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1563210/singlewfrecord.html) Is it just me or should I see some serialized state in there somewhere?

What would happen if I were using a class not marked as [Serializable] in my workflow and tried to persist it?

Comment: Are you hosting under Windows Server AppFabric or vanilla IIS?

Comment: Vanilla IIS. Actually I haven't deployed yet and I'm developing using IIS Express and SSL.

Comment: Are you seeing anything in the event log on the machine - that might show a SerializationException for example?

Comment: No, I'm not seeing anything in the event log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that serialization was being interrupted because of some problems with some types that were used in the workflow.

The first problem was that I had marked a property with [DataMember] that didn't have a set accessor. NetDataContractSerializer wasn't able to serialize that type until I removed the attribute.

The second problem was that I had a workflow variable of type IEnumerable, which obviously isn't marked as Serializable or DataContract. I'm not sure what I was thinking when I did that.

These problems were easy to spot *after* learning about the [WorkflowServiceTraceBehavior on Ron Jacobs blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/05/18/using-workflow-services-and-silverlight-together.aspx).